# Collapsible Onclick function for PNG in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am trying to build a collapsible onclick function in HTML to display an image upon clicking a plus sign to fold out to a src image.
I have accomplished this, but need to program the function to collapse and close the image once I click onto the "-" sign.

Can someone please help me with this?

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `<image style="width= 100%; height:auto" src="https://sharepoint2.web.PNG"/>`;
  document.querySelector('#testButton').innerHTML = '-';
}
```

```html
<button id="testButton" onclick="myFunction()">+</button>
<p id="demo"> </p>
```

Comment: You've got a great start. I encourage a little more experimentation. Then if you get stuck, let us know what you tried and what specifically goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find your image. So, I use stackoverflow site's img. just change that.

```js
var open = false; //Point

function myFunction() {   
  if(open == true){ //If now open
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '';
    document.querySelector('#testButton').innerHTML = '+'; 
    open = false;
  }else{             //If now close
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `<image style="width= 100%; height:auto" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e"/>`; 
    document.querySelector('#testButton').innerHTML = '-'; 
    open = true;
  }    
 }
```

```html
<button id="testButton" onclick="myFunction()">+</button> 
<p id="demo"> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to track whether the button has been toggled or not, you can do this in various ways.

In this example the `onclick` attribute on the HTML element is changed to run a different function:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `<image style="width= 100%; height:auto" src="https://sharepoint2.web.PNG"/>`;
  document.querySelector('#testButton').innerHTML = '-';
  document.querySelector('#testButton').setAttribute('onclick','hideImage()')
}

function hideImage() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ``;
  document.querySelector('#testButton').innerHTML = '+';
  document.querySelector('#testButton').setAttribute('onclick','myFunction()')
}
```

```html
<button id="testButton" onclick="myFunction()">+</button>
<p id="demo"> </p>
```

In this example there is a global variable which tracks if the button has been toggled:

```js
let toggle = false;
function myFunction() {
  if (toggle) {
    toggle = false;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ``;
    document.querySelector('#testButton').innerHTML = '+';
  }
  else {
    toggle = true;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `<image style="width= 100%; height:auto" src="https://sharepoint2.web.PNG"/>`;
    document.querySelector('#testButton').innerHTML = '-';
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="testButton" onclick="myFunction()">+</button> 
<p id="demo"> </p>
```

In this example we use a html data attribute to track the button toggle:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const testButton = document.querySelector('#testButton');
  switch(testButton.dataset.toggle) {
    case "on":
      testButton.dataset.toggle = "off";
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ``;
      document.querySelector('#testButton').innerHTML = '+';
      break;
    case "off":
      testButton.dataset.toggle = "on";
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `<image style="width= 100%; height:auto" src="https://sharepoint2.web.PNG"/>`;
      document.querySelector('#testButton').innerHTML = '-';
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="testButton" data-toggle="off" onclick="myFunction()">+</button>
<p id="demo"> </p>
```